# Condition on Jquery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a page where adding new record in the database is the main function. the page is working fine after one condition is given. one of the fields that is required to be added is the date field. the page has a dropdown of year date (2017,2018.2019). when the selected year in the dropdown for example is 2017, all input should be the date within 2017. inputted date that is less or greater than 2017 should not be validated and not accepted. this goes  the same when the selected year in the dropdwon is 2018 or 2019. accepted input should be the same of the selected year in the dropdown.

I initially used Jquery validate to do the validation.(im just showing the date part in the validation)

**here is the html for the dropdown**

```
<div class="col-sm-2" id="y_type" style="text-align:left;">
<select class="" style="width: 100%; display:inline-block;">
    @{ 
         DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
         for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
      {
           <option>@(datetime.AddYears(+i).ToString("yyyy"))</option>
       }
     }
</select>
 </div>
```

***holiday_date*** in the id of the textfield on the other hand,

**here's the jquery part that does the validation before**

```
 $("form").validate({
        rules:
            { 
                "holiday_date[]": {
                    required: true
                    },
                },
            },


        errorClass: "invalid",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $('#ResultDialog p').html("@hmis_resources.Message.msg_80005");
            $('#ResultDialog').modal();
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            ajaxFormSubmit();
        }
    });
```

What I initially do is create a function that test or compare the textfield of date and the value of the dropdown. But this does not work either. and i am not sure of its placing

```
 function testdate() {

        $(".holidayBody tr").each(function (key, value) {

            var holiday_date = $(value).find(".holiday_date").val();
            if (typeof holiday_date !== 'undefined') {
                var year = holiday_date.substr(6, 4);
                var month = holiday_date.substr(3, 2);
                var days = holiday_date.substr(0, 2)
                holiday_date = year + '/' + month + '/' + days;

                var dropdownear =  $('#y_type :selected').text();
                var result = year == dropdownear;
                alert(result)
            }

        })
    }
```

if there is a simpler way to accomplish this, i would appreciate if you can share.

Comment: Are you getting issue in your testdate() function or calling the function

Comment: the function is running, im just not sure if the logic is correct to properly validate the date input against the selected year

Comment: is there a better way to do it? for correct output?

Comment: There is no such option called `onkeyout`.  [There's `onkeyup` and `onfocusout`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout).

Comment: yes.. just forgot to remove it.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a custom method for the validator, like in this fiddle:
[Validating year from select input.](https://plnkr.co/edit/0tWRyM2gfDFRCeteeoxC?p=preview)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var $select = $("select");

     //I added only the year to the drop down, you should change it to full date.
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
      var year = new Date();
      year.setFullYear(year.getFullYear() + i);
      $select.append("<option value=" + year.getFullYear() + " >" + year.getFullYear() + " </option>");
    }

    // add the rule here
    $.validator.addMethod("thisYearOnly", function(value, element, arg) {

      var selectedYear = value;
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

      return currentYear == selectedYear;

    }, "Must select this year");

    // configure your validation
    $("form").validate({
      rules: {
        mydate: {
          thisYearOnly: true
        }
      }
    });


  });
</script>
```

Comment: I just read in your comments above that you are not sure about the logic of validating the the input has the same year, I will try to help you with this.

Comment: not working, after putting the suggested codes, it is validating immediately even i have not finish inputting a date value

Comment: i added   onfocusout: false,

Comment: I added a fiddle with a working example, it should make your life easier. 
Good luck.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer just copy the code from what I have done and it should work for you.